# How to merge two data.tables with complementary column data in one go?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables, columns v2 of each one are complementary:

```
set.seed(1234)
v1 <- sample(1:20, 5)
v2a <- c(1:2,NA,NA,NA)
v2b <- c(NA,NA,3:5)
id <- c(letters[1:5])

library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = id, v1=v1,v2=v2a)
dt2 <- data.table(id = id, v2=v2b)

dt1
   id v1 v2
1:  a 16  1
2:  b  5  2
3:  c 12 NA
4:  d 15 NA
5:  e  9 NA

dt2
   id v2
1:  a NA
2:  b NA
3:  c  3
4:  d  4
5:  e  5
```

The goal is to merge the two data.tables and have column `v2` with the proper values without `NA`.
I got it correctly done either by:

```
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1,dt2), use.names = T, fill = T)
dt <- dt[,v2:= sum(v2, na.rm = T), by = id]
dt <- dt[!is.na(v1)]
```

or:

```
dt <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "id", all = T)
dt[, v2:=sum(v2.x, v2.y, na.rm = T), by = id][, v2.x := NULL][,v2.y := NULL]
```

both giving the correct desired result:

```
dt
   id v1 v2
1:  a 16  1
2:  b  5  2
3:  c 12  3
4:  d 15  4
5:  e  9  5
```

Is there an easier/one go way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below updates the values of `dt1$v2` where `is.na(dt1$v2) == TRUE` with the values of `dt$v2`, based on id.

```
dt1[is.na(v2), v2 := dt2[ dt1[is.na(v2),], v2, on = .(id)] ][]

   id v1 v2
1:  a 16  1
2:  b  5  2
3:  c 12  3
4:  d 15  4
5:  e  9  5
```

Comment: If the columns are complementary, then just `dt1[is.na(v2), v2 := dt2[.SD, v2, on = .(id)]]` should probably

Comment: @DavidArenburg It works, but I can´t figure out how this syntax works. A `on =`  implies a DT[X] merge format, and as far as I know the data.table to be merged with should be placed in the `i` position. What I am missing?

Comment: @FabioCorrea It does pretty much the same thing as the answer. The join is the same. `.SD` belong to `dt1` and since you already filtered it at the beginning, then `.SD == dt1[is.na(v2)]`

Comment: Got it, `.SD` relates to `dt1` and not `dt2`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is another, less convoluted approach which uses the `fcoalesce()` function which was introduced with `data.table` v1.12.4 (on CRAN 03 Oct 2019):

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(id), v2 := fcoalesce(x.v2, i.v2)][]
```

> ```
>    id v1 v2
> 1:  a 16  1
> 2:  b  5  2
> 3:  c 12  3
> 4:  d 15  4
> 5:  e  9  5
> ```

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(id), v2 := fcoalesce(v2, i.v2)][]
```

works as well because

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(id)]
```

returns

> ```
>    id v1 v2 i.v2
> 1:  a 16  1   NA
> 2:  b  5  2   NA
> 3:  c 12 NA    3
> 4:  d 15 NA    4
> 5:  e  9 NA    5
> ```

Comment: Much cleaner, although it seems to be a bit slower than the one proposed by Wimpel. Thank you.